# Unable to Implement CalendarContract w/ Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, android, calendar, xamarin.android, xamarin

I have been wrestling with the Android Calendar for a couple of days now and I'm at my wit's end.

Following the instructions found here:

http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/calendar/

I have begun a new ICS project and added permissions to read and write to the calendar.  According to the instructions linked above I should now be able to "interact with calendar data by using the CalendarContract class."  However, when I input the first line of example code:

```
var calendarsUri =CalendarContract.Calendars.ContentUri;
```

I get an error saying that "The name 'CalendarContract' does not exist in the current context."

I have download sample code for the CalendarDemo located here:

http://docs.xamarin.com/samples/CalendarDemo/

I can open the project, manipulate the code, deploy it to my test device with the modifications that I have made and it works perfectly.  The problem is that I cannot seem to get CalendarContract to "exist in my context" if I create a project from scratch.  Even adding in the CalendarListActivity.cs into a new project won't work.  This leads me to believe that there is something I have to set in Xamarin Studio, not via code and not indicated in their tutorial, that I have yet to find.

What setting or reference do I need to add into a new or existing project in order to use this feature?  I've looked everywhere I can think of and cannot find the elusive switch, checkbox, reference or whatever is required.  I've burned three days trying to figure this out and I have lost my patience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the error you're having. I created an ICS project in Xamarin Studio and got the same message. I then loaded the solution in Visual Studio and noticed that the CalendarDemo project has a reference to Mono.Android v4.0, but the one created in Xamarin Studio only referenced Mono.Android v2.2 even though I specified Ice Cream Sandwich. That is why you're not able to build.

Changing the Target version in Project Options didn't seem to do anything. A workaround is to add

```
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

to the .csproj file. See the CalendarDemo project as an example.

BTW: This is on Xamarin Studio v4.2.2 (build 2). I don't normally use Xamarin Studio, so I have never had to deal with this. I'm not sure if it's a bug in XS, but it certainly isn't expected behavior.

Just as a test, I created another project in Xamarin Studio, but this time I just selected the standard Android Application project. Surprisingly, it referenced Mono.Android 4.3.0. So apparently there's a bug in the Android Ice Cream Sandwich project template.

I recommend using the standard Android Application project going forward.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Xamarin Studio, right-click on CalendarContact and select Resolve. It should give you two options, first will add "using Android.Provider;" to your using statements and the second will append the code to "Android.Provider.CalendarContract.Calendars.ContentUri"

...or just add manually the using statement. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should import this library

```
> using Android.Provider;
> using Java.Util;
```